# how to save only the minute and second hour in mysql annotation springboot @@ JsonFormat

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am creating a crud with springboot and spring-data where the user saves it in a variable "entry" and I would like it to have only hour: minute: second, I tried using @JsonFormat (pattern = "HH: mm: ss" ) but the error

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "19:47:11": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '19:47:11' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 19:47:11 of type java.time.format.Parsed; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` from String "19:47:11": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '19:47:11' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 19:47:11 of type java.time.format.Parsedat [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 10, column: 20] (through reference chain: br.com.lucas.entity.Acao["entrada"])]
```

how can i save only the hour?

Comment: try with `LocalTime` instead of  `LocalDateTime `

Comment: If you want to extract the "hour" from a `DATETIME` in MySQL, there are several ways(`MID()`, DATE_FORMAT(), ...).  If you don't want to do it there, please remove the tag `'[mysql]'.

Comment: when I use localtime this error:  "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can change formatting in response class by adding `JsonFormat` annotation with pattern parameter. Standard **[SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)** rules apply.

```java
@JsonFormat(pattern = "HH:mm:ss")
private LocalTime localTime;
```

I tried it on a simple example, I want to share with you. If you do not get an error when you try this, but you get an error when you try it in your model, you need to check that the relevant column in the database is `time`, if not, please try so.

Let's create a model to be an example.

```java
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.time.LocalTime;

@Entity
public class Time {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalTime localTime;

    public Time() {
    }

    // getter/setter ..
}
```

Let's create a repository now.

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface TimeRepository extends JpaRepository<Time, Long> {}
```

Let's create a controller now.

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TimeController {

    private final TimeRepository timeRepository;

    public TimeController(TimeRepository timeRepository) {
        this.timeRepository = timeRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = {"/time"})
    public Time time(@RequestBody Time time) {
        timeRepository.save(time);
        return time;
    }
}
```

Now let's send a `Json` request to the `/time` path.

```json
{
    "localTime": "02:30:00"
}
```

You will get a result like this.

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "localTime": "02:30:00"
}
```

I recommend you to read [this article](http://lewandowski.io/2016/02/formatting-java-time-with-spring-boot-using-json/) where you can find more comprehensive solutions.

Comment: Your example is very good and exactly my api lol, I switched to LocalTime and even so when performing the test I get the error

"trace": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect....

thank you very much for the links I will read them. it seems to me that something happens that the bank is not accepting this format

Comment: This example works, *it only stores the time value*. Have you changed the type to `time` of your `LocalTime` field on your database?

Comment: iswailyildiz thank you very much, I didn't realize it and when I did it worked, thank you all